# Implementing Duplicate Membership With Different Membership Form Information

Tags: wordpress, civimember

i have a scenario in which Organizations through their staff apply for permit to build Cell Sites. Now i treat the application as a membership because there is annual renewal fee. Now the challenge is this:

Organizations can apply for fresh permit to build another cell site leading to a scenario where you have one Organization multiple membership/Permits for cell sites. I want a situation where each application/permit can be added to the organization without causing any conflict.

What is the best way to implement this scenario of multiple membership to same organzation.

Also, because each application/permit has different information captured inn the form fields, is there a way to add automatic numbering to each membership form so that specific permit/membership form can be called up and viewed individually?

Currently using Wordpress with Latest Civicrm.

Answer (score 1):

I thought there was an extension out there which permitted this but didn't find it in my quick trawl. The answer will partly depend on what the maximum number of such towers might be.

The original workaround for this was to create multiple membership each 'owned' by a different Organisation (ie when you create the Membership Type, you set up the first type to belong to Org-A, next one to belong to Org-B etc)

You can see a discussion about that here: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=31251.0.html

But as I said i thought there was a way to specify in civi that each 'new' membership be treated as a separate membership and not a renewal (ie avoiding the 'upsell' concept') but the only thread i found about this was https://civicrm.org/blog/eileen/price-sets-memberships-multiple-memberships

Comment: Thank you Pete. The numtilple membership link does not quite apply to my scenario. And also staff of different organizations can apply to build cell sites at different sites. So its imposibble to configure membership type for specific organizations. I had assumed the duplicate rules in profiles will allow multiple membership to thesame person.